# Rails not recognizing unique database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, mysql2

So I have a standard database, then a database that I tie into with readonly permissions to access blogs from a third party blogging platform(ghost).

My database.yml looks like this:

```
staging:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: application
  username: application
  password: XXXXXXXX
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306

staging_blog:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: application_blog
  username: application
  password: XXXXXXXX
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

The migrations seem to run without error when run with the 'staging' environment, but they obviously aren't running against the blog database, as that user only has readonly access to the `application_blog` database.

In my unicorn.stderr.log, I get the following output:

```
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'application_blog' database is not configured. Available: ["staging", "staging_blog"]
```

So I guess my question is... what is necessitating the application blog to be configured in some fashion? How do I make it so that this blog can have a completely different db schema than the `staging` connection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not created the database 'application_blog'.